# Require STARTTLS for sending email in exim

Tags: smtp, exim

I have configured exim to work with dovecot (might be useful to point out) in both IMAP and SMTP auth. I need to make exim require STARTTLS + CRAM-MD5 when a client authenticates to send an email through it, but not for receiving.

I have tried many configuration options, including `client_condition =` (empty) in both LOGIN and PLAIN authenticators. With no luck.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
auth_advertise_hosts = ${if eq {$tls_cipher}{}{}{*}}
```

Comment: If I do that I get a “Relay not permitted” error when trying to send emails. Know why is that?

Comment: You need to make a TLS or SSL connection, and authenticate

Comment: My Thunderbird is configured to use STARTTLS for SMTP. Is that OK?

Answer (score 0):

Add the "server_advertise_condition" option to your exim authenticator. For instance:

```
server_advertise_condition = ${if eq{$received_port}{587}{${if eq{$tls_in_cipher}{}{no}{yes}}}{no}}
```

This option offers authentication only if received port is 587 and connection is encrypted.