# How to force STARTTLS in Exim?

Tags: exim, starttls

I am learning to set up a mailserver. I got it working with postfix, now trying the same configuration with Exim. How can I force a client to take up only STARTTLS connection for SMTP outgoing connection? I followed the instructions in this question.

[Require STARTTLS for sending email in exim](https://serverfault.com/questions/476097/require-starttls-for-sending-email-in-exim)

My config looks now as following

```
MAIN_TLS_ENABLE = yes
MAIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
MAIN_TLS_PRIVATEKEY = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

.ifdef MAIN_TLS_ENABLE
# Defines what hosts to 'advertise' STARTTLS functionality to. The
# default, *, will advertise to all hosts that connect with EHLO.
.ifndef MAIN_TLS_ADVERTISE_HOSTS
MAIN_TLS_ADVERTISE_HOSTS = *
.endif
tls_advertise_hosts = MAIN_TLS_ADVERTISE_HOSTS

auth_advertise_hosts = ${if eq{$tls_in_cipher}{}{}{*}}
```

Restarted Exim, no errors.
Then I ran some tests in http://checktls.com/

The TestSender passed, I could send email under secure communication. But TestSenderAssureTLS failed, the website could negotiate an unencrypted communication.

What am I missing?

When I create an account with Thunderbird, it autodetects an unsecure SMTP channel, not one with STARTTLS. Setting up the account and sending email succeeds. However, when I make an SMTP conversation from the shell of a computer in the network, no authentication is advertised. It looks as follows:

```
EHLO <subdomain>.<domain>
250-betelgeuse Hello <subdomain>.<domain> [10.0.14.34]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP
AUTH LOGIN
503 AUTH command used when not advertised
```

Could somebody point me to what I am missing, how I can make better tests?
On a related topic, how I can advertise the configuration I wish to the clients doing autdetect?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `STARTTLS` connection needs to start unsecured.  The `STARTTLS` option is not advertised until after the first `EHLO` command.  If you want to enforce `STARTTLS` you will need to add or modify an `ACL`.  I published the [Email Policy I apply](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/email-policy/).

If this server is your MX, you should not enforce `STARTTLS` on all connections.  My configuration  requires `STARTTLS` for connections requiring `AUTH`.  This does not include connections from my LAN, but does apply to users sending email from my server while roaming.  I also require authentication occurs on the submission port.  This is the basics of the `ACL` I use.

```
# This access control list is used after an auth command.
acl_local_auth:

# Deny authentication on unencrypted links
deny
  !encrypted = *
  message = AUTH encryption is required

# Deny if AUTH isn't on submission port (autolist enabled)
deny
   !condition = ${if eq {$interface_port}{587}}
   message = AUTH requires submission port

# Accept if encrypted (should not get here if unencrypted)
accept
  encrypted = *
```

# Default deny
  deny
    message = AUTH not accepted

You could also enforce `TLS` in a mail `ACL`.  This ACL allows external senders to send mail in.

```
# This access control list is used for every MAIL FROM command in an
# incoming SMTP message. 
acl_local_mail_from:

# Accept if locally trusted hosts
accept
  hosts = : +relay_from_hosts

# Accept if authenticated
## May want to check domain is local
accept
  authenticated = *

# Accept the null sender - bounce messages and receipts
accept
  senders = :

# Accept if not local domain - recipient ACL will handle relaying
# More checks on sender in recipient ACL.
accept
  !hosts = : +relay_from_hosts
  !sender_domains = +local_domains

# Default deny
deny
  message = $sender_address is not authorized to send email on this connection.
```

You should consider using `defer` instead of `deny` while testing the ACLs. The ACLs are enabled by adding `acl` statements to the main section of the configuration, and the above ACLs to the ACL section.

acl_smtp_auth = acl_local_auth
  acl_smtp_mail = acl_local_mail_from

Answer (score 0):

According to your settings...

```
tls_advertise_hosts = MAIN_TLS_ADVERTISE_HOSTS
auth_advertise_hosts = ${if eq{$tls_in_cipher}{}{}{*}}
```

you require TLS connection to advertise authentication so initiate a connection with openssl:

```
openssl s_client -connect hostname:25 -starttls smtp
```